# JavaScript array and object in single variable?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I recently came across some code which I am a little confused about. Below is similar code, have a look:

```
var x = [];
console.log(x); // prints [] (no surprise)
x[0] = "abc";
console.log(x); // prints ["abc"] (no surprise)
x["test"] = "testing"
console.log(x); // prints ["abc"] 
console.log(x.test); // prints "testing"
```

so in this case.. the same variable, `x`, is both array and an object. How is this possible? If it acts as both, then `console.log(x)` should print something like `["abc",test:"testing"]` but that syntax is wrong.

So whats happening in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All Arrays are Objects, (not only them, everything in JavaScript is an Object (except the primitives though))

```
console.log([] instanceof Object);
// true
```

just that they are special kind of objects which process integer keys differently.

So, you can expect them to act like normal JavaScript Objects. You can add arbitrary properties to them.

About the `console.log` result,

```
[ 'abc', test: 'testing' ]
```

is just a representation given by the implementation. If the representation has a `key : value` format, then it is a normal property associated with that array. That's all.

Comment: *"everything in JavaScript is an Object"* Well...except the things that aren't, like primitives. But *most* things in JavaScript are objects, indeed.

Comment: "just that they are special kind of objects which process integer keys differently". can you elaborate on that? .. if i understand correctly an array is something like `{1 : value1,2 : value2}` etc?  but is displayed [value1,value2] is that it ?

Comment: @raj Arrays are ordered collection of data. So, you don't have to explicitly show the index corresponding to each of the elements. That is why the representations normally omit that.

Comment: To be a bit more precise, "everything in Javascript is or can be promoted to an Object". Example : `(1).toFixed(3) === "1.000"`  , so here `1` was considered as `new Number(1)`